# Having git parent repo and 2 childern repo Using VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm mostly TFVC guy but I have a task to setup a git repo, in VSTS, and then have 2 child repos from that parent.
Each of this VSTS repo's belongs to a different live account owned by a different firm. basically each want to have their isolated repo and have control over when the changes pass between the parent and their child repo. 
People are using all 3 of these repos to work on the same code base and a file can be modified in any of these 3 repo and nothing should be lost during the merge so there is a good chance of the merging issues.
These children must be able to get changes from the Parent (on demand), and eventually children need to be merged back into the parent, and I want to keep all the history details of the child in parent and vice versa.
What are my options to handle this scenario?

Comment: Child/Parent does not make much sense to me in regards to Git. Are you talking about forked repositories?

Comment: You have three different Team Services accounts? (`<xxx>.visualstudio.com`)

Comment: @DanielMann yes kinda! 3 different firms (2 consultings) and one is for client.

Comment: @crashmstr Parent/child are terms to explain my scenario not necessary correct from technical terms stand point.  You can call it fork but I don't know how you could fork a repo to make another repo hosted by VSTS. Is it possible?

Comment: @DanielMann the solution for 3 different account should not be different from 3 team projects in the same account. the point it that each of this repo should be considered as an external repo from other 2 repos perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Git working mechanism is quite different from TFVC. When you treat the two repos as the children repo, the code will be exist in the parent repo. So it doesn't need to merge back into the parent.

There are some options can help for your situation: [**submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and
 [**subtree**](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree).

#### 1. Add the two children repositories as submodules for the parent repo

```
# In the parent repo
git  submodule add <URL for child1>
git  submodule add <URL for child2>
git commit -m 'message'
git push
```

When you make/commit changes the two children repo and want to push the changes to the remote of the children repo separately, you can use:

```
git submodule foreach "git push"
```

If the children repo updated on the remote and you want to get the latest changes from the remotes, you can use:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

#### 2. Use subtree to add the children repos as two folders on the parent repo

```
# In the parent repo
git subtree add --prefix=child1 <URL for child1 repo> master
git subtree add --prefix=child2 <URL for child2 repo> master
git commit 
git push
```

If you want to push changes to the children remote repo, you can use:

```
git subtree push --prefix=child1 <URL for child1 repo> master
git subtree push --prefix=child2 <URL for child2 repo> master
```

If you want to get the changes from children remote repo to the parent repo, you can use:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=child1 <URL for child1 repo> master
git subtree pull --prefix=child2 <URL for child2 repo> master
```

---

For **adding remotes** of the children repositories to parent repo, the files from the children repos can't be added to the parent repo's working directory automatically:

```
# add remote and fetch children repos
git remote add child1 <URL for child1> -f
git remote add child2 <URL for child2> -f
```

Even you can checkout the files from children repos, but they located in different branches (branch_child1 and branch_child2) in parent repo:

```
git checkout -b branch_child1 child1/master
git checkout -b branch_child2 child2/master
```

If you want to show the files from children repos and parent repos together, you can merge branch_child1 and branch_child2 into master branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch_child1
git merge branch_child2
```

Note: if files in parent repo and children repos are in different subfolders, you can merge smoothly. Else it will make mess for the working directory.

In a word, if your condition meet any one of below aspects, you can use `git remote add`. else, you'd better no use this way:

- it's ok for you to locate files from different repos in different branches.
- files in different repos are in the different name of folders.

Comment: Thanks ! I have to try this, but based on what I see in option 2 (subtree) the push/ pull are targeting master. So my question is: does this keep track of history of all branches? let's say there is a branch named feature1 created in child1 repo, and it has been merged into its master. then at the time of pulling from the child, would parent get the feature1 branch history as well? Or it has to be done for each branch separately

Comment: Yes, the subtree add/pull/push only works for **a certain branch**. And the child repo history won't exist in parent repo, it only get the current version of child repo files for a certain branch. If you want add files both in `master` and `feature1` branch of child repo to the parent, you can add another subtree: `git subtree add --prefix=child1_feature1 <URL for chile1 repo> feature1`.

Comment: what about this remote repository approach?  https://help.github.com/articles/about-remote-repositories/

Comment: `git remote add` is also a way. But it needs some conditions. I give the detail operation and the potential trouble in the last part of my answer. Of cause, if you meet any one of the conditions I listed, you can feel free to use `git remote add`.